# getParentKeyFieldName() on null if Schedulertask is executed by cronjob

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I forked the extension sf_event_mgt and created some schedulertasks. 
If i call execute() with an userFunc in frontend or start the task manually all works fine. But if i call the schedulertask by cronjob with `/var/www/[...]/cli_dispatcher.phpsh scheduler` i always get

> Call to a member function getParentKeyFieldName() on null in /var/www/[...]/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapper.php:447

The error seems to occur directly after instantiating these objects:

```
$this->objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$this->eventRepository = $this->objectManager->get(EventRepository::class);
$this->notificationService = $this->objectManager->get(NotificationService::class);
```

After commenting out the repository line, no exception is shown.

I already cleared all caches and checked php annotations.

Used PHP Version: 7.1.17 and TYPO3 Version: 7.6.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an Solution:

Extbase Reflection Cache does not work as expected if php7.0-igbinary is installed

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/56603#note-8